# Amazon EC2 - Issue Connecting to Public DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connection

I am facing a few issues.
I initially had assigned an elastic IP to my micro instance i-38cbc940, but for some reason, after I did that the webpages I had uploaded were not functioning properly (images not loading correctly, etc).

I tested this prior to the elastic IP assignment and such problems were not occurring. So I dissociated the elastic IP address and released it. Then, I reboot my instance.

The problem is, now I cannot view my site in a browser using the public DNS address listed (ec2-23-23-18-52.compute-1.amazonaws.com) or any of its sub-directories.

Things I Know:

1. My security settings have not changed - I still have the same security group identified with the instance.
2. httpd.conf file still shows "/var/www/html" as the DocumentRoot.
3. Every time I navigate to the public DNS address listed...it shows "could not connect" but if I ping it, it works.
4. If I SSH into the instance in the var/www/html directory, everything is still there, including an index.html file that was viewable before. Also, I can get into the instance through PuTTY.

Also, no sure if it's important, but this is an AmazonEC2-AMI/Apache/MySQL server with Wordpress CMS installed.

Any ideas on what could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to check the apache conf for any hardocoded dns entries of your instance amazon dns and also check your code for any referrals to the amazon dns of your instance.